# clang error: function definition declared 'typedef'

Tags: ios, objective-c, clang

I am using clang to compile my code, but I get an error, the code and the error are as follows:

```
/Users/fenglihai/llvm/llvm_build/Debug/bin/ClangConfuse /Users/fenglihai/Desktop/Test/Test/ITXAppdelegate.m /Users/fenglihai/Desktop/Test/Test/main.m /Users/fenglihai/Desktop/Test/Test/MainViewController.m /Users/fenglihai/Desktop/Test/Test/VTEnumType.h /Users/fenglihai/Desktop/Test/Test/ITXAppdelegate.h /Users/fenglihai/Desktop/Test/Test/MainViewController.h -- -w -std=gnu11 -fobjc-abi-version=2 -Wnullability-completeness -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk -isystem /Users/fenglihai/llvm/llvm_build/Debug/lib/clang/9.0.0/include -Wnull-dereference -fobjc-weak -ObjC -mios-simulator-version-min=8.0 -ObjC -lSDWebImage -lSVProgressHUD -lYYCache -lYYCategories -lc++ -ljcore-ios-1.2.6 -ljpush-ios-3.1.2 -lpop -lresolv -lsqlite3 -lz -framework Accelerate -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreImage -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreText -framework Foundation -framework ImageIO -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -weak_framework UserNotifications -I/Users/fenglihai/Desktop/Test/Test -I/Users/fenglihai/Desktop/Test/Test -I/Users/fenglihai/Desktop/Test/Test -I/Users/fenglihai/Desktop/Test/Pods/Headers/Public -I/Users/fenglihai/Desktop/Test/Pods/Headers/Public/JPush -I/Users/fenglihai/Desktop/Test/Pods/Headers/Public/SDWebImage -I/Users/fenglihai/Desktop/Test/Pods/Headers/Public/SVProgressHUD -I/Users/fenglihai/Desktop/Test/Pods/Headers/Public/YYCache -I/Users/fenglihai/Desktop/Test/Pods/Headers/Public/YYCategories -I/Users/fenglihai/Desktop/Test/Pods/Headers/Public/pop
```

i get the error:

```
/Users/fenglihai/Desktop/Test/Test/VTEnumType.h:13:44: error: function definition declared 'typedef'
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, VTLayoutStyle) {
                                           ^
/Users/fenglihai/Desktop/Test/Test/VTEnumType.h:15:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'VTLayoutStyleDefault'
    VTLayoutStyleDefault,
    ^
/Users/fenglihai/Desktop/Test/Test/VTEnumType.h:17:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'VTLayoutStyleDivide'; did you mean 'VTLayoutStyle'?
    VTLayoutStyleDivide,
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    VTLayoutStyle
/Users/fenglihai/Desktop/Test/Test/VTEnumType.h:13:29: note: 'VTLayoutStyle' declared here
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, VTLayoutStyle) {
                            ^
/Users/fenglihai/Desktop/Test/Test/VTEnumType.h:19:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'VTLayoutStyleCenter'; did you mean 'VTLayoutStyle'?
    VTLayoutStyleCenter,
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    VTLayoutStyle
/Users/fenglihai/Desktop/Test/Test/VTEnumType.h:13:29: note: 'VTLayoutStyle' declared here
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, VTLayoutStyle) {
                            ^
4 errors generated.
Error while processing /Users/fenglihai/Desktop/Test/Test/VTEnumType.h.
```

VTEnumType.h

```
#ifndef VTEnumType_h
#define VTEnumType_h

/** 导航栏布局样式 */
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, VTLayoutStyle) {
    /** 默认样式，item自适应文本宽度，间距由itemSpacing决定 */
    VTLayoutStyleDefault,
    /** items等分导航条宽度，常用于item数较少时 */
    VTLayoutStyleDivide,
    /** 导航栏居中布局，间距由itemSpacing决定 */
    VTLayoutStyleCenter,
};



#endif /* VTEnumType_h */
```

ITXAppdelegate.m

```
#import "ITXAppdelegate.h"
#import "VTEnumType.h"

@interface ITXAppdelegate ()
@property (nonatomic, assign) VTLayoutStyle height;
@end

@implementation ITXAppdelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    self.height =VTLayoutStyleDefault ;
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Hi Lh, welcome aboard! It's hard to see exactly what's going on here-- ideally you can narrow down the piece of code that is causing the error and post the code in question. In your case, the error looks to be `error: function definition declared 'typedef' typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, VTLayoutStyle)` Also check out this page which might help with your enum definitions: https://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/

Comment: ok ~I have added my code

Comment: I am using SWIFT_ENUM macro but its showing error only on simulator on Xcode 12.4. On Xcode 11.3.1 it runs without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're building your project via that direct command line to clang, then I think what's happening is you're specifying the header files (.h) to clang as source files, which they are not.

This is the error you would get if the `NS_ENUM` macro is not available-- the compiler is just getting confused about what you're trying to do there. That macro is usually made available via the standard Foundation and Cocoa include headers, but if the compiler is trying to treat your header file as a source file in its own right, then that header doesn't include Foundation, so the enum stuff isn't defined at that point.

More to the point, you should only ask clang to compile source units (.m). The compiler will see the references to the headers as it goes along, and load them in via the preprocessor as required. If it can't *find* a header that it needs while doing this, it will let you know.

Answer (score 1):

You should import Foundation before you define your `enum`:

```
@import Foundation;
```

I suppose the header file was imported in a bridging header file.